# Show a checkbox item for a show page in which I don't need a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I would like to show a checked box that's not clickable for a show page within my React-Redux application. So I'm familiar with building a form for adding and editing purposes but for a form that just shows the data, I'm unfamiliar as to how to go about that.

```
<label>Check if they ever were a World Champion</label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="champion"
                            defaultChecked={true}
                            value={champion}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <br></br>
```

This is what I have in my adding a fighter and updating forms:

```
return (
        <div>
            <h1>{list.attributes.title}</h1>
            <Link to={`/lists/${list.id}/edit`}>Edit This List Name</Link>
            <ol>{list.attributes.fighters.map(fighter =>
                <li>
                   <p>{fighter.name}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.alias}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.nationality}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.division}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.stance}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.height}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.reach}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.status}</p>
                   **<???>{fighter.champion}</???>**
                   <p>{fighter.win}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.loss}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.draw}</p>
                   <p>{fighter.ko}</p>
                </li> 
            )}</ol>
        </div>    
    )
```

This snippet is from my ListCard in which the user can see the fighters for their particular list but can not edit that information on this page.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a checkbox in HTML? Because that's just `<input type="checkbox">` You'd probably what to wrap that in a `<label><input type="checkbox" checked>{fighter.champion}</label>`

Comment: Well not to create a checkbox for a form but to show whether if the fighter was a Champion or not through a disabled checkbox (I have another route where the user can update solely the individual fighter's information. This page however just show the list's name and gives the user the option to change just the list's name while still showing all the fighters associated with that list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to disable a checkbox? So yes then you can do this by adding "disabled" in your element. Or if you want to handle it with the condition then you need to import Input from reactstrap and then you can do this by adding disabled=true or false.

install the package:

```
npm install reactstrap
```

and write a code:

```
Import { Input } from reactstrap;

<label>Check if they ever were a World Champion</label>
                        <Input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="champion"
                            defaultChecked={true}
                            value={champion}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            disabled=true
                        />
                        <br></br>
```

Comment: Hi Farhan, it's not the top half of the code that I need help with but the bottom half. The top half was code from where the user can add a fighter to the database and choose an existing list all on that form. The bottom half code is for when the user can edit the list name. I just wanted to show to the user the fighters associated with the list but not for the user to use it as a form just mainly to reflect all the information that is saved to that particular fighter.